# Wait for Electron window to be a specific URL?

Tags: node.js, electron

So I am writing an application in Node.js and Electron, and I am trying to login through Google on the same session, then get another URL. I have the session working and the login to Google working, but when I login to Google, I want it to switch and load another URL. The current idea I have is something like this:

```
win.loadURL('https://accounts.google.com/').then(() => {

});

setInterval(() => {
    while (!win.webContents.getURL().includes("myaccount.google")) {
        if (win.webContents.getURL().includes("myaccount.google")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    clearInterval();
}, 100);

win.loadURL('http://' + url);
```

I just don't know what else to do, I know this is fairly spaghetti but I've tried so many things and nothing seems to work correctly. I feel like I shouldn't even be doing a while loop at all because it seems to freeze my browser (understandably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the event ['did-navigate'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-navigate). I would like to but I can't test this for you at this time.

Also: electron webview navigation event

Comment: Sorry was out, trying it now.

Comment: Much love, works amazing. I looked at events before I posted this and must have not looked hard enough.